# Unable to access and reuse controls from other page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use a page to access some controls in a different page but for some reason, it's not working despite setting the necessary references to the other page? Any ideas on why this is not working and how this can be fixed?

*Expected result:*

Open app > MainList > click list item > go to PageSunflower > PageSunflower should show controls of the PageTest.xaml file

*Current result:*

> Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

**MainList.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainList : Page
 {
     public List<ListItem> listItemMains;

     public MainList ()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         listItemMains = ItemManagerMains.GetListItems();
     }

     private void ListMain_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
     {
         ListItemMain item = (ListItemMain)e.ClickedItem;

         if (item.FlowerName == "Sunflower")
         {
             Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageSunflower));
         }
         else
         {
             Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageDaffodil));
         }
     }
 }
```

**PageSunflower.xaml**

```
 <Page [...]>
     <Grid>

     </Grid>
 </Page>
```

**PageSunflower.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class PageSunflower : Page
 {
     public PageSunflower()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         TabView tabview = PageTest.Current.MyTabs;

         TextBlock txtTitle = PageTest.Current.txtPageTitle;
         txtTitle.Text = "hello";
     }
 }
```

**PageTest.xaml**

```
 <Page [...]>
     <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
             <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" x:FieldModifier="public"/>

         <controls:TabView x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyTabs"/>
     </Grid>
 </Page>
```

**PageTest.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class PageTest : Page
 {
     public PageTest()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         Current = this;
     }

     public static PageTest Current;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the control of other page through static variables, you need two conditions:

1. This page has already been loaded.
2. The page is cached.

Since the controls on the page are called, the controls on the page will be instantiated only after the page is loaded.

In addition, when the page is not the content of the current `Frame`, the page may be unloaded, and the reference will be released at this time, the control cannot be obtained, so the page should be cached.

So if you want to get the controls in a page, please make sure that the page has been loaded (that is, once navigated to the page), and then cache the page, like this:

```cs
public PageTest()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    Current = this;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How would I make sure that the page has been loaded when I'm not navigating to it at all? This is the part that I don't get in terms of how to fix it.

Comment: If you do not want to navigate to this page, please try to create an instance of this page before getting the controls of this page, for example: `var test = new PageTest()`.

Comment: The page now loads without crashing, but appears blank. Does the `NavigationCacheMode` code still need to be there?

Comment: Caching a page refers to caching an instance of the page in the current Frame. If you do not need to navigate to this page, you do not need to cache the page

Comment: I still do not understand why the page appears blank when I already added a TextBlock inside and set the text for it.

Comment: Based on the content of your question, the page you are currently displaying is PageSunflower, not PageTest. Then no matter how you set the content of PageTest, it will not affect the display of PageSunflower. Only when navigating to PageTest, you can see your changes to PageTest content.